# Mysql - count it works without groupby clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm confused with count aggregation function.

Below sentence is mysql and it worked without a groupby clause.
how could it be possible?

```
SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM    dual;
```

result : 1

Is there any parameter that groupby clause is default when count aggregation function called.

help me out plz.

Answer (score 7):

Aggregation functions such as `COUNT()`, `SUM()` and `AVG()` are used in aggregation queries.  Such queries calculate the values based on groups of rows that are summarized into a single row in the result set.

Normally, an aggregation query uses a `GROUP BY` to define the rows in the result set.  The result set has one row for each unique combination of the `GROUP BY` keys found in the data.

When such a query does not have a `GROUP BY`, then the entire table is considered a group and it is summarized into exactly one row.  Incidentally, this is true even when there are no rows in the table.  The result would be a count of `0`.